# generate best grades of students query

Tags: php, sql

I'm work on project of CMS script who make some function for teacher

and from this function there's function i made it name

generate the best grades for student who got from A or A+ or A-

this is my statement

```
SELECT s.name,c.name,g.grade 
FROM `courses` c ,`grades` g,`students` s 
WHERE g.grade like "%A%"
```

but the problem is that the fetched data is like duplicate more than one time

i mean for the same student it duplicate 5 time i don't know why !

Comment: Never use commas in the `from` clause.  When you fix the `join` syntax, your query will work.

Comment: how i can fix it ! ?

Comment: Of course you get duplicates, you are not linking (joining) your tables. [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=joining+tables) and learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.name,c.name,g.grade FROM `courses` c ,`grades` g,`students` s WHERE s.student_id = g.student_id and c.course_id = g.course_id and g.grade like "A+"
```

i fix the problem by add some where for student and grade table

Comment: alternate answer just in case ...`g.grade IN ('A','A+','A-')`